# Prevent cursor loading animation when using subprocess.call()

Tags: python, arduino, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to create a Python program that takes input from an Arduino to change the monitor's input port. Currently everything works fine, but when the program runs, the cursor on Windows shows a spinning circle constantly. It's super annoying, and  I found out that it is related to the fragment of code below.

```
# Check serial monitor to see if button has been pressed
while True:
    try:
        data = arduino.readline()[:-2]
        if data:
            ... Some irrelevant code ...
        # Check if input has changed unexpectedly
        elif (subprocess.call(r'ControlMyMonitor.exe /GetValue "\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0" 60', startupinfo=si) == 15 and current == 17) or (subprocess.Popen(r'ControlMyMonitor.exe /GetValue "\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0" 60', startupinfo=si) == 17 and current == 15):
            print("Detected monitor switch")
            if current == HDMI:
                arduino.write('1'.encode())
                current = DP
            elif current == DP:
                arduino.write('2'.encode())
                current = HDMI
    except:
        sys.exit("Communication to Arduino was interrupted")
```

I'm calling the program ControlMyMonitor.exe multiple times every second to validate the input port value, which is causing the cursor to spin forever when the program is running. Is there a way to prevent this, or should I give up on checking if the monitor input has changed unexpectedly (i.e. no device connected to HDMI port after switching manually, and monitor automatically switches back to DP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by cutting out the middleman. I added a file called moncontrol.py which is pasted below the original fragment of code with my changes. I added the function "get_monitor_input" which returns an integer value of the monitor selected. This way, the code can stay relatively the same.

```
from datetime import datetime
from ctypes import windll, WinError
import time, os, sys, serial, moncontrol

while True:
        handles = []
        for handle in moncontrol.iter_physical_monitors(False):
            handles.append(handle)

        try:
            data = arduino.readline()[:-2]
            currMon = moncontrol.get_monitor_input(handles[monitor], 0x60)
            if data:
               ... irrelevant code ...
            # Check if input has changed unexpectedly
            elif (currMon == DP and current == HDMI) or (currMon == HDMI and current == DP):
                if current == HDMI:
                    arduino.write('1'.encode())
                    current = DP
                elif current == DP:
                    arduino.write('2'.encode())
                    current = HDMI
                else:
                    destroyHandles(handles)
        except serial.SerialException:
            destroyHandles(handles)
            createLog()

        destroyHandles(handles)

def destroyHandles(handles):
    for handle in handles:
        windll.dxva2.DestroyPhysicalMonitor(handle)
```

moncontrol.py:

```
from ctypes import windll, byref, Structure, WinError, POINTER, WINFUNCTYPE
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HMONITOR, HDC, RECT, LPARAM, DWORD, BYTE, WCHAR, HANDLE


_MONITORENUMPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HMONITOR, HDC, POINTER(RECT), LPARAM)


class _PHYSICAL_MONITOR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('handle', HANDLE),
                ('description', WCHAR * 128)]


def iter_physical_monitors(close_handles=True):
    """Iterates physical monitors.
    The handles are closed automatically whenever the iterator is advanced.
    This means that the iterator should always be fully exhausted!
    If you want to keep handles e.g. because you need to store all of them and
    use them later, set `close_handles` to False and close them manually."""

    def callback(hmonitor, hdc, lprect, lparam):
        monitors.append(HMONITOR(hmonitor))
        return True

    monitors = []
    if not windll.user32.EnumDisplayMonitors(None, None, _MONITORENUMPROC(callback), None):
        raise WinError('EnumDisplayMonitors failed')

    for monitor in monitors:
        # Get physical monitor count
        count = DWORD()
        windll.dxva2.GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, byref(count))

        # Get physical monitor handles
        physical_array = (_PHYSICAL_MONITOR * count.value)()
        windll.dxva2.GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, count.value, physical_array)
        for physical in physical_array:
            yield physical.handle
            if close_handles:
                if not windll.dxva2.DestroyPhysicalMonitor(physical.handle):
                    raise WinError()


def get_monitor_input(monitor, code):
    current = DWORD()
    windll.dxva2.GetVCPFeatureAndVCPFeatureReply(monitor, code, None, byref(current), None)
    return current.value


def set_vcp_feature(monitor, code, value):
    """Sends a DDC command to the specified monitor.
    See this link for a list of commands:
    ftp://ftp.cis.nctu.edu.tw/pub/csie/Software/X11/private/VeSaSpEcS/VESA_Document_Center_Monitor_Interface/mccsV3.pdf
    """
    if not windll.dxva2.SetVCPFeature(HANDLE(monitor), BYTE(code), DWORD(value)):
        raise WinError()
```